# IndexOutOfBoundsException while using stanford naturalli.OpenIE

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I'm using the `naturalli.OpenIE` module from coreNLP. I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException while using combined options `-triple.all_nominals true` and `-format reverb`. Please tell me how can I fix it. This is my line command:

```
java -mx2g -cp "/almac/ignacio/corenlp/*" edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE -filelist $HOME/list -triple.all_nominals true -format reverb > trip
```

where the input is a sentence-by-row file. This does not occur if I use the mentioned options differently, e.g. `(-triple.all_nominals false, -format reverb)` or `(-triple.all_nominals true, -format ollie)`.

This is my input file:

```
the ability of IHF alone to activate fimB expression show IHF to repress ompC transcription
Thus , NanR and NagC appear to activate fimB expression independently .
Thus MarA is able to repress the rob promoter after the preformed open complex clears the promoter .
However , in vitro experiments show IHF to repress ompC transcription from two of its three promoters .
These results show that constitutive and inducible expression of the chromosomal MarA was able to upregulate nfnB expression in contrast with the lack of activation mediated by constitutive expression of the chromosomal SoxS and Rob proteins .
The Rob homologs MarA and SoxS can activate transcription of a broad range of genes in vivo ( reviewed in references 2 and 14 ) , including sodA , fumC , micF , zwf , and inaA , suggesting broadly overlapping activities of these three regulators .
It thus seems likely that the ability of IHF alone to activate fimB expression is enhanced in the D3 mutant background
In conclusion , MelR and CRP bind to the melAB promoter co - operatively to adjacent sites in order to activate transcription in a co - dependent manner
```

This is the output, which I get multiple times in the log.

```
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [1.1 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator lemma
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator depparse
Loading depparse model file: edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/english_UD.gz ... 
PreComputed 100000, Elapsed Time: 2.424 (s)
Initializing dependency parser done [6.8 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator natlog
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator openie
Loading clause searcher from edu/stanford/nlp/models/naturalli/clauseSearcherModel.ser.gz...done [0.210 seconds]
Processing file: /almac/ignacio/rie_gce/karla_tests
All files have been queued; awaiting termination...
/almac/ignacio/rie_gce/karla_tests  0   ability show    IHF 1   2   9   10  10  11  1.000   the ability of IHF alone to activate fimB expression show IHF to repress ompC transcription Thus , NanR and NagC appear to activate fimB expression independently . DT NN IN NN RB TO VB NN NN VBP NN TO VB NN NN RB , NN CC NN VBP TO VB NN NN RB .    ability show    ihf
/almac/ignacio/rie_gce/karla_tests  0   NanR    activate    NagC    17  18  22  23  19  20  1.000   the ability of IHF alone to activate fimB expression show IHF to repress ompC transcription Thus , NanR and NagC appear to activate fimB expression independently . DT NN IN NN RB TO VB NN NN VBP NN TO VB NN NN RB , NN CC NN VBP TO VB NN NN RB .    nanr    activate    nagc
/almac/ignacio/rie_gce/karla_tests  0   IHF repress ompC transcription  10  11  12  13  13  15  0.620   the ability of IHF alone to activate fimB expression show IHF to repress ompC transcription Thus , NanR and NagC appear to activate fimB expression independently . DT NN IN NN RB TO VB NN NN VBP NN TO VB NN NN RB , NN CC NN VBP TO VB NN NN RB .    ihf repress ompc transcription
/almac/ignacio/rie_gce/karla_tests  0   NanR    activate independently  NagC    17  18  22  26  19  20  1.000   the ability of IHF alone to activate fimB expression show IHF to repress ompC transcription Thus , NanR and NagC appear to activate fimB expression independently . DT NN IN NN RB TO VB NN NN VBP NN TO VB NN NN RB , NN CC NN VBP TO VB NN NN RB .    nanr    activate independently  nagc
/almac/ignacio/rie_gce/karla_tests  0   NanR    activate    fimB expression 17  18  22  23  23  25  1.000   the ability of IHF alone to activate fimB expression show IHF to repress ompC transcription Thus , NanR and NagC appear to activate fimB expression independently . DT NN IN NN RB TO VB NN NN VBP NN TO VB NN NN RB , NN CC NN VBP TO VB NN NN RB .    nanr    activate    fimb expression
/almac/ignacio/rie_gce/karla_tests  0   NanR    activate independently  fimB expression 17  18  22  26  23  251.000 the ability of IHF alone to activate fimB expression show IHF to repress ompC transcription Thus , NanR and NagC appear to activate fimB expression independently . DT NN IN NN RB TO VB NN NN VBP NN TO VB NN NN RB , NN CC NN VBP TO VB NN NN RB .    nanr    activate independently  fimb expression
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.util.RelationTriple.toReverbString(RelationTriple.java:373)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE.tripleToString(OpenIE.java:604)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE.processDocument(OpenIE.java:638)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE.lambda$main$12(OpenIE.java:760)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
DONE processing files. 1 exceptions encountered.
```

I'm using `stanford-corenlp-3.6.0.jar`

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please post the full stack trace so I can see where the IndexOutOfBoundsException is occurring.

Comment: What version of CoreNLP are you using? Also, could you post the file (or preferably a subset of the file) that's failing? The extractor seems to be producing a malformed triple, but it's hard to debug without an example.

Comment: Hi... is there is tehre a possible track of this problem? Thanks

Comment: Thank you, the problem is solved in the latest version of code in the git repo.